# Manually adding labels to axis on a Date-sclaed variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I'd like to add to the first plot those labels shown in the second plot while preserving the Date labels that are already there.

[image: LEFT][image: RIGHT]

Doing the typical

```
P1 + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(startDate, endDate), labels= c("startDate", "endDate"))
```

doesn't work.  I can transform dat$x but then I lose the date labels.

**Is there something I can add to `P1` to get the labels appended (ideally without having to change the code for creating P1)**

**Bonus points**: Is it possible to knock just the single-label from the months that would overlap with the other labels?

#### Sample Data & Code:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(date=1:200 + 15e3, value=rep(1:20, each=10) + (rnorm(200, 0, .5)))

startDate <-  dat$date[[30]]
endDate   <-  dat$date[[42]]

P1 <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=as.Date(date, origin="1970-01-01"), y=value)) + geom_line() +
        geom_vline(xintercept=c(startDate, endDate), color="blue") +
        xlab("Date")

P2 <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=date, y=value)) + geom_line(alpha=0) +
        geom_vline(xintercept=c(startDate, endDate), color="blue") +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(startDate, endDate)
                         , labels= c("startDate", "endDate")) +
        theme(axis.text.x =element_text(angle=45) )
```

Comment: There are no ticks (only labels) in the second plot, at least assuming you mean x-axis ticks.

Comment: Thanks @Dwin for correcting my terminology.  I've edited the title and content of the question

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to set manually all breaks and labels. For this you need to know range of your date values, then set positions of breaks (I set them as first day of month). And for labels also manually added names (including startDate and endDate).

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=as.Date(date, origin="1970-01-01"), y=value)) + geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=c(startDate, endDate), color="blue") +
  scale_x_date("Date",
   breaks = c(seq(from=as.Date("2011-02-01"),to=as.Date("2011-08-01"),by="month"),
                      as.Date(c(startDate, endDate),origin="1970-01-01")),
   labels= c("Feb" ,"Mar" ,"Apr", "May", "Jun" ,"Jul" ,"Aug","startDate", "endDate")) +
  theme(axis.text.x =element_text(angle=45))
```

As the start and end dates are close to `Mar` label, you can set it to blank (`""`) but gridline for this date will remain as `breaks=` are not changed.

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=as.Date(date, origin="1970-01-01"), y=value)) + geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=c(startDate, endDate), color="blue") +
  scale_x_date("Date",
   breaks = c(seq(from=as.Date("2011-02-01"),to=as.Date("2011-08-01"),by="month"),
                      as.Date(c(startDate, endDate),origin="1970-01-01")),
   labels= c("Feb" ,"" ,"Apr", "May", "Jun" ,"Jul" ,"Aug","startDate", "endDate")) +
  theme(axis.text.x =element_text(angle=45))
```

[image]

Comment: If you set the second `labels` character argument to "", you could grab the bonus points.

Comment: +1 for the helpful answer, thank you.   I am still curious if there is a way to add the second labels without needing to go back and grab the data from the first plot